# The required QueryBuildDataSource was not found in the Query associated with the FormDataSource

Tags: axapta, dynamics-ax-2012

I've extended the `SalesTableListPage` to include a new column taken from a display method on `CustTable` now my users are getting the error:

> The required QueryBuildDataSource was not found in the Query associated with the FormDataSource . The QueryBuildDataSource should have the same name and table ID as the FormDataSource.

[image: The Objects in question]

To gain access to the display method I had to:

1. Add `CustTable` to the `SalesTableListPage` Query
2. Re-Select the `SalesTableListPage` Query on the Data Sources node of the `SalesTableListPage` Form.
3. Add a new StringEdit on the grid and set it to `CustTable` `CityName_BR`

I can't replicate this error with my admin or my non-admin user and I don't understand where this error comes from.

- One post says that if you have a Query on the menu item that opens the Form then that query needs the same data sources as the query on the form. *But I don't have a query on my menu item*
- Other suggestions state that I need to add the new data source "in the Table related queries". *I am unaware of such a setting in AX 2012*
- Other suggestions refer to queries written in code. *mine are AOT queries*

**Update**: It seems the reason I wasn't getting the error was that I had the CueGroup `EPCustRelatedInfo` or just `CustRelatedInfo` collapsed. When I unfold this part I am getting the error as well.

Resolving that Cue Group has led me to several menuitems with queries attached. The culprit seems to be the `SalesTableListPageOpen` menu item and query of the same name (which references the query I have changed).

I am however still confused as to how to actually fix the error since the `SalesTableListPageOpen` query just says `Composite Query\SalesTableListPage`. Unsetting/resetting the referenced query, restoring and re-compiling the query has not had any effect...

Comment: "But I don't have a query on my menu item" may be this is the reason why you can't replicate this issue. Ask your users which menu item they use.

Comment: @AliaksandrMaksimau They use the same I do...

Comment: Usually when something doesn't work for some (but not all) users, it is either related to usage data or security. Have you tried resetting the usage data of the users and giving them the system administrator role to check if this resolves the issue?

Comment: I haven't been able to reproduce this issue, having added CustTable to the query and expanded the 'Related info' cue group in the list page.

Answer (score 0):

I think one of your suggested solutions is probably correct. Just investigate the query though and you should be able to figure out what's happening.

At the bottom of `\Classes\SalesTableListPageInteraction\initializeQuery` just put:

> `info(_query.toString());`

Then open the menus `All sales orders` and `Open sales orders` and you'll see the query differences. Then repeat opening various menu items with different users and see what results.

You may need to move the location of the `info` line, but the concept is there.

Comment: Thanks. But that didn't lead me to any solution. I have found something else out. But I don't know how to fix it yet.